# Plotting a Grid (with Graphics + Text) in TeX?

Tags: graphics, grids

**Question:** Using resources from the TeX universe, what is the best way to create a graph similar to the one below (i.e., a 2x2 matrix with different images at different coordinate locations, with text underneath).

> [image]

Comment: You could use `tikz` ;)

Comment: A `tcolorbox` poster could be of help too

Comment: If you're using ```beamer slides```: Add the horizontal rule underneath the frame title; include the graphic in the top right corner; right the text in small letters (under the rule); draw with Ti*k*Z the grid (and the crossed cell); include all the graphics at the rigth position (as ```node```s); place as ```node``` the yellow boxed blue text at the rigth site of the four cells; draw lines with arrows from the origin to the corners with ```node```s (positioned with ```node[midway,below] …```; also make paths for each part of the line).